# I can't get inventory(); to run

Tags: c#

I am new to c# i have learnt the language basics and i am trying to make a text based rpg where you type in a command and then it does a command.
I have currently put it so that i can open the inventory but the inventory function won't run and i don't know why.
It does'nt give an error. Sorry for the messy coding. I have labeled the function with a comment. Hopefully it helps.

````
//lists
using System.Collections.Generic;

//dont know how to rename file
namespace Security_program
{//create an rpg class which most of my functions is
    class RPG
    {
        public List<string> _inventory = new List<string>();
        public List<string> usable_items = new List<string>();
        public void set_items()
        {
            usable_items.Add("Health potion");
        }
//\/this is the part i need to run \/sorry for messy code
        public void inventory()
        {
            bool in_inventory = true;
            while(in_inventory == true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _inventory.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(_inventory.Count == i)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have nothing in your inventory!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine( i+1 +". "+_inventory[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        //uses command input funcction and knows what to do withn it



        public void action(string action)
        {
            if(action == "i")
            {
                inventory();
            }
        }//takes command inputs
        public string command_check(string command)
        {//quit in case they dont want to play anymore(impossible but ok i guess)
            if(command=="!quit")
            {
                string t = "q";
                return t;
            }//if they dont want to quit they can do stuff
            else if(command == "!inventory")
            {
                string t = "i";
                return t;
            }
            else
            {
                string t = "n";
                Console.WriteLine("Makea decision!");
                return t;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RPG rpg = new RPG();
            rpg.set_items();
            bool GameEnd = false;
            while (GameEnd == false)
            {
                string Text = Console.ReadLine();
                string action = rpg.command_check(Text);
                if(action == "q")
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    rpg.action(action);
                }
                
            }
            Console.WriteLine("You died!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: It does run, you just never put anything inside `_inventory` so the for loop doesn't run (the `if` statement doesn't really make sense, if `_inventory.Count == 0` then `i < _inventoryCount` is never `true`)

Comment: You need the check for an empty inventory outside of the for loop and I seriously doubt you want an infinite while loop

Comment: Also, you're not changing the value of `in_inventory` anywhere. Your `while` loop is infinite.

Comment: `inventory()` runs if you type "!inventory" according to your code. Hoewer you'll run to an endless loop because you never turn `in_inventory` to false in the while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have made two changes, refer the comments for explanation

```
public void inventory()
            {
                bool in_inventory = true;
                while(in_inventory == true)
                {
                   /* The loop termination condition is till i < _inventory.Count, so your if 
                        condition ie. _inventory.Count == i will never be true. 
                        So change your loop condition to i <= _inventory.Count
                    */
                    for (int i = 0; i <= _inventory.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if(_inventory.Count == i)
                        {
                            /*
                                Set value in_inventory = false; here as all _inventory items are visited.
                                Possibly you can remove the while loop, as the for loop iterates through all _inventory items.
                            */
                            in_inventory = false;
                            Console.WriteLine("You have nothing in your inventory!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        Console.WriteLine( i+1 +". "+_inventory[i]);
                        }
                    }
    
                }
            }
```